# ::jQuery:: If text contains link (http / https), this link should be image src

Tags: jquery

I am having a table data with text, image url's etc.

If any td contains link, this has to be wrpped inside img and src should be this text

> **Example Code**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>https://amp.dev/static/samples/img/product1_640x426.jpg</td>
         <td>Apple</td>
         <td>1.99</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>https://amp.dev/static/samples/img/product2_640x426.jpg</td>
         <td>Orange</td>
         <td>0.99</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

> **Disired Output**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td><img src="https://amp.dev/static/samples/img/product1_640x426.jpg" /></td>
         <td>Apple</td>
         <td>1.99</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td><img src="https://amp.dev/static/samples/img/product2_640x426.jpg" /></td>
         <td>Orange</td>
         <td>0.99</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you can try something like `$('td').html(function(i,text) {return text.replace(/\bhttps:\/\/([\w\.-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}\/.+\b/gi,'<img src="$&"/>');});` but aint tested

Answer (score 1):

Working example as per **Carsten Løvbo Andersen** comment

```js
 
$('td').html(function(i,text) {return text.replace(/\bhttps:\/\/([\w\.-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}\/.+\b/gi,'<img src="$&"/>');});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>https://amp.dev/static/samples/img/product1_640x426.jpg</td>
         <td>Apple</td>
         <td>1.99</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>https://amp.dev/static/samples/img/product2_640x426.jpg</td>
         <td>Orange</td>
         <td>0.99</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```